# Adding Fields to Display in Search Results

Tags: search, search-results

I would like to change what information is displayed under each individual result on my results page. Currently it seems to show a summary of the content, followed by the author and sometimes the date. I'd like to change this by adding a few of my fields including things like "Client ID" and "Client Name" which get filled out in an InfoPath form and then promoted to SharePoint.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this by customizing the `Display Templates`. Every result type has it's own display templates. That you can find inside `/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/`. So make sure you take a look at below given links.

Here is the thing you are looking for:

[Introduction to SharePoint 2013 Display Templates](http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/)

[Creating customized search results in SharePoint 2013](http://www.abelsolutions.com/totm/creating-customized-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013/)